# How do I create a project using Material 3 with default theme?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

I want to create a new Android project and use `Material 3`. However Android Studio offers no template with `Material 3`. I can use the regular template with `Material 2` and update the dependencies manually, but then I am still left with an now incompatible `Material 2` theme that's coming from the Android Studio template.

How do I get the default Material 3 theme in that case?

Comment: Have you tried updating you Android studio version?

Comment: oh, indeed my fault. I was just looking at the wizard if it mentions material 3. indeed a new project includes material 3 dependencies, thanks!

Comment: @stefan.at.kotlin Can I see your `theme.xml` file code?

Comment: @MDEV Thanks, but already solved. Just create a new proejct in Android Studio and it will be Material 3 :-)